# Git unable to find branch a tag belongs to

Tags: git, git-branch, git-tag

I have a list of tags in my project, listed e.g. as follows:

```
(develop)$ git tag
v2.0.0
v2.0.1
```

I am able to find the branch that the first tag belongs to, but not so for the second one;

```
/home/pkaramol/Workspace/gitlab/myproject
(develop)$ git branch --contains tags/v2.0.0
* develop
/home/pkaramol/Workspace/gitlab/myproject
(develop)$ git branch --contains tags/v2.0.1
```

How is it possible that a tag exists but does not belong to a branch?

Comment: I agree it is a duplicate and we can proceed with closing this one;

Answer (score 1):

Tags are just names associated with commits. Branches are essentially names associated with commits that have a special treatment that moves the name to point to a new commit if you create a new commit on that branch.

There's no requirement that a tag "belong" to a branch or vise-versa.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed the `-a` flag to include remote refs in my query:

```
(develop)$ git branch -a --contains tags/v2.0.1
  remotes/origin/stable/v2.0
```